# UART connection to MCU

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, digital-logic, uart

I have a UART module that needs to be connected to an MCU.

The pins are Open drains.

The input base current is 1.16mA. Output Current 96mA. Hope its fine.
Anything I missed or I need to take care of with the transistor (CB configuration) or others?

Comment: We have no knowledge what voltages your device accepts as inputs, so we can't answer if something works or not. Why are the pins open-drain anyway?

Comment: @Justme The module seems to have UART TX and RX pins. They are mentioned as open-drain in the datasheet. Since, the device (module) is working on a Vcc of 5V. I assume that's the output we need to do level shifting to from the MCU. Right?

Comment: It would read in the data sheet what levels are acceptable. Don't assume.

Comment: "The pins are Open drains" - which pins?

Comment: @Finbarr, UART TX and RX pins in the UART module are open drain.

Comment: @Justme, Sure, this circuit would work right? The CB configuration and the other resistor values? Do you find anything that I need to take care of apart the voltage level that you mentioned?

Comment: Please edit your question (**don't** add info in comments) and add (a) the manufacturers and part numbers for both of the UARTs and (b) links to the datasheets and/or user manuals for both. Without that, it's impossible to give a definite answer. Thanks.

Comment: 96mA IO pin current would generally exceed absolute maximum rating for almost all MCUs. Why not tell us which UART module and which MCU you are using, and provide links to data sheets. Also 9600 BPS rate would have fastest square wave of 4800 Hz.

Comment: @Justme, If I try to reduce the 96mA current by increasing the pull-up resistor, the output voltage goes down? 1. Any idea why is that happening? 2. Also, you mean to say 9600baud rate translates to 4.8kHz? And should I take care of something when you mean "would have fastest square wave of 4800Hz?

Comment: The fastest square wave would be seen when transmitting a pattern like 01010101. As each bit is a complete cycle of the 9.6 kHz clock, the effective frequency would be 4.8 kHz

Comment: @Finbarr,thank you. So, on the MCU transmit side, Tx speed will be set to 9600baud. Hence, the frequency will be 4800Hz, right? The receiver UART module will receive UART signals with the 4800Hz frequency and same 9600 baud rate correct?

Comment: Please don't change your question radically as you've done by editing it. It usually makes answers redundant and people will have put effort into writing those answers. You didn't add any detail. It's reasonable that it was then closed.

Comment: No, the frequency isn't 4800 Hz. It varies according to the pattern of data being sent and received, with the highest fundamental component being 4800 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

Some 3.3V MCUs have 5V tolerant IO, this means they can't actively drive outputs to 5V, but they can accept 5V input. If your 3.3V MCU has 5V tolerant IO then you will not need a level converter and can tie GPIO configured as open-drain outputs to 5V with a resistor.

You have not said which MCU is being used or which device it connects to, so I can't be more specific.

Your circuit looks like it could work. R2 is too low though, that will be a lot of current draw, you only need about 10k pull up for UART.

I am not a fan of BGT transistors as they draw a lot of current (in relative terms) and also can be very slow switching and suffer from turn-off delay caused by over-saturation which is very difficult to avoid when implementing a switching circuit as supposed to a linear analogue circuit. To overcome turn-off delay caused by over-saturation you end up having to drive the BGT transistor with even lower impedance, i.e. even higher currents, or develop a more complex circuit. A low frequency of 9.6 kHz is not difficult to achieve with BGTs though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  If I try to reduce the 96mA current by increasing the pull-up resistor, the output voltage goes down? Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Is the output loaded, or open circuit in the simulation?

Comment: Output is open circuit in the simulation.

Comment: You could try reducing resistor R1, if the issue is caused by slow switching times. Is the output high voltage too low with a constant voltage, or is it that the output takes too long to settle?

Comment: I think you would have an easier time using a level converter IC

Comment: The other question is what voltage is the input driving HIGH to?